# Filter a table and return all values which meet multiple criteria from another table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have an excel workbook which has 3 sheets; Sheet1 contains a table called Spend_2022, Sheet2 2 contains a table called All_Spend, Sheet 3 is called Auto_Pop. My intention is for a user to select a Supplier # from the dropdown on the Auto_Pop sheet and return all unique rows from All_Spend using Spend_2022 as the filter (though not necessarily by using the Excel function of the same name)

**Spend_2022** represents a combination Item # + Item Name + Supplier # + Supplier Name for purchases made in 2022; however, it does not contain Manufacturer # or Manufacturer Name.

**All_Spend** represents a combination Item # + Item Name + Manufacturer # + Manufacturer Name + Supplier # + Supplier Name for all purchases made; however, it does not contain specific purchase dates.

Below you will find a representation of the tables and the Auto_Pop page. I have tried using Index + Match, Filter, and various combinations of if statements to no avail. I would like to try to solve this with formulas if possible.

**Sheet1 - Spend_2022**

| Item #(7) | Item Name | Supplier Num(6) | Supplier Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0123456 | First Item | 012345 | First Supplier |

**Sheet 2 - All_Spend**

| Item #(7) | Item Name | Mfg #(6) | Mfg Name | Supplier Num(6) | Supplier Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0123456 | First Item | 543210 | First Mfg | 987456 | First Supplier |

**Sheet 3 - Auto_Pop**

| Supplier Num(6) | Supplier Name |
| --- | --- |
| -Dropdown Menu- | -Auto Filled- |

| Item #(7) | Item Name | Mfg #(6) | Mfg Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0123456 | First Item | 543210 | First Mfg |

Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide to aid in solving this issue.

Tried using filter function on All_Spend to return values when Spend_2022[Supplier #]=Auto_Pop[Supplier #] and All_Spend[Supplier #]=Auto_Pop[Supplier #] and Spend_2022[Item #]=Auto_Pop[Item #] and All_Spend[Item #]=Auto_Pop[Item #]

I was able to use filter function for each table and return an array containing only unique values when Spend_2022 and All_Spend[Supplier #]=Auto_Pop[Supplier #]
`=UNIQUE(FILTER(Spend_2022,Spend_2022[Supplier #]=Auto_Pop!$A$2,"Check Ref Table")`

I also tried to filter the array from another filter (nested filter) to no avail. I made sure to use Ctrl + Shift + Enter for these array formulas.

Comment: it seems that all the information is available in the All_Spend table, not sure what you want to include the Spend_2022 table. How does it make a difference?

Comment: @TerryW All_Spend shows all purchases made in the last 5 years but none of the entries have dates. Whereas the Spend_2022 has all purchases made in 2022 but is missing the manufacturer ID and Name. 

The idea is that I know what was purchased in 2022 based on Item #/Name +Supplier #/Name but I am missing the Manufacturer #/Name which can be found in All_Spend

Comment: Suggest you add another sheet using the All_Spend data, add the additional columns to look up the missing information from Spend_2022, then you can do the filter based on this new table to get the desired data

Comment: Hello @TerryW, I ended up using this suggestion (with some modification) and this was indeed the solution! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @TerryW and @Ike for responding to this post! I ended up finding a solution for this issue.

On the All_Spend Sheet I added a column "UserSel" and used the below formula to return TRUE or FALSE. This formula checked the values in the current row. This formula checked whether the Supplier Num(6) matched the user's
selection, counted if the supplier number and item number in the row matched any row found in the Spend_2022 sheet and returned TRUE or FALSE if this count was >0.

=AND([@[Supplier Num(6)]]='Auto_Pop'!$B$2,(IF(COUNTIFS(All_Spend[Supplier Num(6)],[@[Supplier Num(6)]],Spend_2022[Item Number - 7 Digit],[@[Item #(7)] digits']]]),TRUE,FALSE)))

I then used the below formula on the Auto_Pop sheet in cell A4 which returned a filtered array containing all unique rows from All_Spend for which UserSel=TRUE.

=IFERROR(UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(All_Spend,All_Spend[UserSel]=TRUE,""),2,1,4),FALSE),"No Valid Items Found")